# Setting the correct execution directory (root path) in ASP.NET Core (Service/IIS)

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-core, .net-core

I'd like to publish my ASP.NET Core web app both targeting *netcoreapp2.0*, where it can run in a console environment or inside IIS or as a traditional *net462* app which allows running as console or Windows service. For this I need to set the correct root paths, but ASP.NET Core is still lacking documentation about it.

Most examples fetch the root path using `Directory.GetCurrentDirectory()`, but there's also `PlatformServices.Default.Application.ApplicationBasePath` through the [Microsoft.Extensions.PlatformAbstractions](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Extensions.PlatformAbstractions/) nuget package. One seems to provide the source directory, the other points to the execution directory.

There's also the possibility to set both the **Content Root** and the **Web Root** for the `WebHostBuilder`, <strike>unfortunately I haven't found a proper explaination about their difference</strike> (*webroot is from where static content should be served, content root is the app directory*).

What and how are the correct paths to be set in which scenario (...IIS, console) so that e.g. the ASP.NET Core infrastructure is able to pick up its files (config, static files, web pages)?

Comment: Your question is not clear. The execution directory is based on where the assembly is executing *from*. In other words, if you run the program published to netcoreapp2.0, then the executing directory will be netcoreapp2.0. Likewise with net462. Each has its own set of assemblies. There's no single executable that then somehow picks one of those to run.

Comment: @ChrisPratt Yes, obviously. What I am looking for is how to configure the ASP.NET Core infrastructure so that it works both when running as a web app in IIS and as e.g. a console or Windows service and is able to pick up the files from the right directory.

Comment: Still not clear what you're looking for here. The executable will pick up the files in the directory it's executing from, which will naturally be the "right directory" depending on which target you run.

Comment: This is complicated a little since windows services will run from window's system32 folder by default In [my sample for a netcoreapp windows service](https://github.com/dasMulli/dotnet-win32-service/blob/master/samples/MvcTestService/Program.cs) I propose to set the directory when configuring the windows service. The need to work from the working directory OR the directory where the dll file is in then varies between a published output and development environments (VS/`dotnet run`)